# Calculating error on slope of graph

Tags: statistics, regression, data-analysis, linear-regression, slope

I'm trying to find the rate of change and the error on that rate based on 7 measurements points and the assumption that the trend is linear. My calculations are below:

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|c|c|}
\hline
\text{Position (mm)} & \text{Height (mm)} & \text{Slope} & \text{Slope}^2 \\ \hline
191 & 115 \\\
256 & 110 & -0.077 & 0.006 \\\
333 & 105 & -0.065 & 0.004 \\\
391 & 100 & -0.086 & 0.007 \\\
480 & 95 & -0.056 & 0.003 \\\
528 & 90 & -0.104 & 0.011 \\\
617 & 85 & -0.056 & 0.003 \\\hline
\end{array}
$$

$$
\begin{array}{|c|c|}
\hline
\left<s\right> & -0.07410 \\\
\left<s\right>^2 & 0.00549 \\\
\left<s^2\right> & 0.00579 \\\
σ^2 & 0.00030 \\\
σ & 0.01725 \\\
Δ & 0.00771 \\ \hline
\end{array}
$$

I've been told that my calculated standard deviation is not correct because the slopes are not independent of each other (they share points).

Is this a valid way to calculate error on a slope?

What other methods are available to calculate error on a slope based on limited points?

Answer (score 1):

You simply need to use linear regression. Using your data, this would give
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 128.31945  & 0.80174 & \{126.09345,130.54545\} \\
 b & -0.0708000 & 0.00189 &  \{-0.0761557,-0.0656441\} \\
\end{array}$$